# Regulus Black was never mentioned in movies, but was in a book. Why?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison

I have no recollection of any mention of Regulus Black in the *Harry Potter* films. However, I felt he was an important part of the story, especially because:

> Dumbledore and Harry found a [Horcrux](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Salazar_Slytherin%27s_Locket) which was almost [destroyed by Regulus Black (R.A.B)](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Regulus_Black).

Is there a reason he wasn't included in the movie? Or was he; and I missed it?

Comment: He was a memorable phenomenon in the books because of the cliffhanger at the end of the 6th book, that had only the initials.  If that wasn't there, I doubt so many of us would remember his name so well...

Comment: I'm surprised you forgot that. :|

Answer (score 24, accepted):

He was mentioned in the Deathly Hallows, Part 1, at exactly the right spot, where they are trying to figure out who R.A.B. is in Sirius's house...

Comment: I have probably missed that part.

Comment: The problem in the movie is because they literally skim right over it, where as in the book they look at the family tree, and bring up his name in a bunch of conversations.

Comment: It was skimmed over so quickly in the film that friend, who hadn't read the books, didn't even understand what that was all about.

Comment: Well, you can only do so much cramming a 600+ page book into a movie, even if you divide it into two parts...

Answer (score 17):

Regulus Black was indeed referenced in two of the Harry Potter movies.

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Professor Slughorn, upon his first meeting with Harry inside the house Slughorn is occupying in the village of Budleigh Badderton, shows Harry a picture of himself sitting with several former Slytherin Quidditch players. Slughorn specifically points out Regulus Black to Harry. Slughorn, as former Head of House for Slytherin, laments that he did not have Sirius Black in Slytherin House, as well as Regulus, as Sirius was sorted to Gryffindor.

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* Regulus Black's initials -- R.A.B. -- appear as the signature on the note found inside the fake Slytherin locket Horcrux, which was recovered from Voldemort's deadly potion basin in the sea cave by Harry and Dumbledore. While it is not revealed in *Half-Blood Prince* that these initials indeed belong to Regulus Black, this fact is confirmed in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* Part One.

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* Part One, Harry is shown looking around Sirius Black's childhood bedroom at No. 12 Grimmauld Place. Ron calls to Harry from downstairs and when Harry joins Ron and Hermione there, Ron points out the name plate on Regulus Black's bedroom door that reads "Regulus Arcturus Black". Hermione reads the name out loud and Ron confirms "R.A.B.".

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* Part One, while the trio is interrogating Kreacher the House-elf at No. 12 Grimmauld Place regarding the missing Slytherin locket Horcrux, Kreacher briefly recounts the story of how Regulus Black gave Kreacher the locket Horcrux and ordered Kreacher to destroy it, before Regulus died. Kreacher confirms he was unable to follow Regulus's order to destroy the locket; Kreacher was not told the locket was a Horcrux, and therefore would not have known the proper way to destroy such an evil, dark artifact.

That's my story and I'm stickin' to it :)

Answer (score 3):

To put more details for what Pearson mentioned:

In that specific scene at Grimmauld place they are looking around the house, and see several doors with occupants' names on them. The next door has "Regulus Arcturus Black" - at which point someone (Hermione IIRC) does a double-take and goes "Regulus... R. A. B.".

In the next scene they discuss the locket with Kreacher the house-elf, including the orders by RAB to destroy it and the fact that Mundungus stole the Horcrux.

Pretty closely follows the book, as far as I recall, though I don't seem to remember the movie scene where Harry gave RAB's real locket that Dumbledore and he retrieved from the basin back to Kreacher..

Answer (score 3):

Regulus Arcturus Black is indeed mentioned in the movies. However, as a person he was dead before he first book. Book 7 has Kreacher recounting his memories of that time, which if reproduced page-for-page would have increased the DH1 movie by several minutes without the audience gaining much (other than that RAB wasn't quite as black as he was painted). He was still mentioned both at the end of HBP and the beginning of DH1, as the person of RAB was still important for getting the locket out of Voldemort's hideout and into the Black house (thus setting up the next major set piece at the Ministry).